# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'checkpoint'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am implementing the below link and getting a TensorFlow version error. I am working in Pycharm under Conda environment.

https://github.com/ZhaoJ9014/High-Performance-Face-Recognition/tree/master/src/Look%20Across%20Elapse-%20Disentangled%20Representation%20Learning%20and%20Photorealistic%20Cross-Age%20Face%20Synthesis%20for%20Age-Invariant%20Face%20Recognition.TensorFlow

I tried many versions, in some versions, the problem has been solved but the GPU available is False. The problem is in the version I didn't find any compatible version in which the GPU available is True.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.6.0, 1.5.0, 1.8.0
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/train_main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import modeleag as M 
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/modeleag.py", line 1, in <module>
    import layers2 as L 
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/layers2.py", line 36, in <module>
    class Layer(tf.contrib.checkpoint.Checkpointable):
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/AAAIFace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, item)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'checkpoint'
```

Comment: Try 1.4.0 . Many old developers use the old version 1.4.0

Comment: And install the right version cuda if you want to use gpu .

Comment: Now getting this error: ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I have Cuda 11.0

Comment: 8.0 is not available

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14622) may help you for the above error. Thanks!